# Using data inside component with Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-directives

just starting with VueJS and trying to figure out how to use multiple components inside vue instance with separated data and methods.

so my HTML looks like that

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">

        <add-domain v-if="component === 'add-domain'">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Add domain</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <i aria-hidden="true" class="ki ki-close"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>URL (*)</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="url" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button @click="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                        Add
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </add-domain>

    </div>
</div>
```

right now there is only one component "add-domain" but there should be more.

my Vue script

```
    var Modal = new Vue({
    el: '#modal',
    data: {
        component: false
    },
    components: {
        'add-domain': {
            data: function() {
                return {
                    url: ''
                }
            },
            methods: {
                submit: function() {
                    console.log(this.url);
                }
            },
            template: '<div><slot></slot></div>'
        }
    }
})
```

as you can see i set "v-model="url" at my html input, and trying to change it inside "add-domain" component, but it's not working, same goes for the "submit" method inside "add-domain" component.

not sure what exactly i do wrong.

Thank's in advance.

Comment: `data`, `method`, `computed` and so on, should be go outside `components`, at same level as `components`

Comment: Ah, so there is no way to separate those thing when there is a lot if components to be added? ://

Comment: You should define your components outside of where you mount your Vue app, then in your mounting block you can just reference them by name: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Local-Registration

Comment: Also you will need to explicitly make your `url` and `submit` properties accessible inside your component's `<slot>`, e.g. `<slot :url="url" :submit="submit">`. Then, change your component tag to: `<add-domain v-slot="{ url, submit }">`. However I don't know if you will be able to update the `url` from inside the slot.

Comment: I agree with @Hannah on defining your components outside.  I also recommend learning and using the Vue CLI to create Single File Components.  Might not always need it depending on your application, but good to know IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would recommend rewriting your code:

1. Define your `add-domain` component before you mount your Vue app to keep things more organised and easy to read.
2. Pass down the methods and data from your component that you will need inside your `<slot>` content.
3. Create a `changeUrl` method in your component and pass this down as well to allow your slot content to update the URL value.

```
const addDomain = {
  data: function () {
    return {
      url: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    submit: function () {
      console.log(this.url);
    },
    changeUrl(ev) {
      this.url = ev.target.value;
    },
  },
  template:
    `<div>
      <slot :url='url' :submit='submit' :changeUrl='changeUrl'>
      </slot>
    </div>`
};

var Modal = new Vue({
  el: "#modal",
  data: {
    component: false
  },
  components: {
    addDomain
  }
});

// HTML:
<add-domain v-if="component === 'add-domain'" v-slot="{ url, changeUrl, submit }">
  ...
  <input
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    :value="url"
    @input="changeUrl"
  />
  ...
</add-domain>
```